# анимация появления сообщения

Tags: javascript, css

сообщения появляются снизу блока, я сделал анимацию на появление самого сообщения.

```js
$('#ck').click(function(){
  $('.inner').append('<div class="block">Сообщение</div>');
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px;
  color:white;
  animation: error .3s;
}
.cont {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
@keyframes error {
    0% {
        transform: scale(.2);
    }
    25% {
        transform: rotate(7deg) scale(1)
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(-7deg)
    }
    75% {
        transform: rotate(7deg)
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ck">клик</button>
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
```

мысли в голову не приходят как сделать так что б когда сообщение снизу появляется, оно плавного сдвигало остальные сообщения вверх(сейчас мгновенно).
ну или если у вас есть другие идеи, как сделать не навящивое и плавное появления сообщений такого вида, выслушаю ваши предложения

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('#ck').click(function(){
  $('.inner').append('<div class="block">Сообщение ' +
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 0)) + '</div>');
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 6px 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px;
  color:white;
  animation: error .4s;
}
.cont {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
@keyframes error {
  0% { height: 0px; margin-top: -16px; }
  100% { height: 20px; margin-bottom: ''; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button id="ck">клик</button>
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
```